# Sort an ArrayList of semicolon separated values by a field

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of semicolon separated values that needs to be sorted by the second field of each of the ArrayList elements.

Each of the elements of the array list have the form:

```
  field1;field2;field3;field4
```

and need to be sorted by field.2 Is there a way to do this without having to create a temporary array, switch `field1` and `field2`, sort that array, and then switch `field1` and `field2` again?

Thank you for any help you might be able to offer

Comment: What do you mean sorted by the second field? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Say 'field2' is a customers last name and 'field1' is the customers first name, and the array list needs to be sorted by last name

Comment: @Katie If that's the case, why not just create a class to represent a `Customer` and sort those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will do it for you:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>(){
    @Overide
    public int compare(String s1, String s2){
        return s1.split(";")[1].compareTo(s2.split(";")[1]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to write a `Comparator<String>` that extracts the second field and compares it. No intermediate array needed. Just a bit of substring/indexof/regex/[substringBetween](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringBetween%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I haven't used the Comparator before, but I'll look it up, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, to create own [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and use [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) something like

```
Collections.sort(yourArrayList, new Comparator<String>(){
       @Overide
       public int compare(String s1,  String s2){                 
            String s1Field2, s2Field2;
            // Do your extracting of field 2 for each String
            s1Field2 = s1.split(";")[1];
            s2Field2 = s2.split(";")[1];
            // You may also want to add to this to ensure that the original strings 
            // do contain a 'field2'
            return s1Field2.compareTo(s2Field2);
       }
   });
```